# Free shapefile designer

Tags: shapefile, google-maps, software-recommendations

I am using health mapper to display health data. It uses ArcGIS to draw district boundaries as a shapefile. I am interested to to draw sub district boundaries, e.g County or neighborhood boundary shapefile.

As ArcGIS is not free, any idea how to do it using a free software applied on Google Maps to define the county?

Answer (score 1):

[QGIS](http://qgis.org) is a free alternative to ArcGIS. You can add OpenLayers plugin to get background map and create your required boundary.